# Get the first value of a list that match some criteria and then set posterior values to zero in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have many 1D list of this form:

```
[   0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  , 9216.24,
    9441.44, 9584.14]

[   0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    9040.62, 9320.95, 9454.16, 9564.21, 9647.48, 9694.4 , 9734.68,
    9762.59, 9788.14]
```

and I would like to find the first value bigger than zero, and then set all posterior values to zero, in this way.

```
[   0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  , 9216.24,
    0., 0.]

[   0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    9040.62, 0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  , 0.]
```

I'm pretty sure that there is a very pythonic way to do this. It could be in python list or numpy array.

Thanks

Comment: There's a difference between `then set all the other values to zero` and `posterior values to zero`. Which one is it?

Comment: Also, is it a regular 2D array, ie does all lists have equal number of elements?

Comment: It's just a 1D array, and is posterior.

Comment: Can we assume that all the lists have equal number of elements? Also, is it a 1D array or 1D list?

Comment: 1- yes, 2- Is a list, but could be solved as a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your 1D list into a numpy array, look for the 1st non-zero element, and set all following elements to 0:

```
x = numpy.array([0., 0., 0., 1., 2., 3.])
x[x.nonzero()[0][1]:] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

use `next` function to find the index of first element that meets condition, then simple list comprehension to set 0 to all but the element met criteria:

```
a = [   0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    9040.62, 9320.95, 9454.16, 9564.21, 9647.48, 9694.4 , 9734.68,
    9762.59, 9788.14]
    
ind = next(iter for iter,x in enumerate(a) if x>0)
b = [0 if i!=ind else a[ind] for i in range(len(a))]
print(b)
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9040.62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

you can also create the output by create list with all zeros and set the number in it's place:

```
b = [0]*len(a)
b[ind] = a[ind]
```

of course - leads to same result

Answer (score 1):

If would recommend using `numpy` for this kind of operations. Should be faster and more efficient than using loops.

If you wanna just keep the first non zero element and zero out all the others, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array([   0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,    0.  ,
    9040.62, 9320.95, 9454.16, 9564.21, 9647.48, 9694.4 , 9734.68,
    9762.59, 9788.14])
    
indices_nonzero = np.nonzero(array_1)

# Ignore the first non zero index from the filter, set all other values to zero
array_1[indices_nonzero[0][1:]] = 0.0

print(array_1)
```

The output should be:

```
[    0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.                                                                                                                       
     0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.    9040.62     0.                                                                                                                       
     0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.       0.  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
l = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9040.62,
 9320.95, 9454.16, 9564.21, 9647.48, 9694.4, 9734.68, 9762.59, 9788.14]9454.16, 9564.21, 9647.48, 9694.4, 9734.68, 9762.59, 9788.14]
index, value = next(filter(lambda t: t[1] > 0, enumerate(l)))
result = l[:index] + [l[index]] + [0] * (len(l) - index - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using np.argwhere to obtain the index of the first match. This solution also works for multidimensional arrays with respect to lexicographical ordering.

```
result = np.zeros(a.shape)

try:
    firstIndex = np.argwhere(a > 0)[0].tolist()
    result[firstIndex] = a[firstIndex]
except IndexError:
    raise ValueError("No positive value in this array")
```